# Can't access bool variables in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, boolean

The part of this code where it says `if (bar = true)` it can't find the variable "bar" that I create in `if (foo == "True")` or `if (foo == "False")`.

Code:

```
string foo = Console.ReadLine();

if (foo == "True") {
    bool bar = true;
}
if (foo == "False") {
    bool bar = false;
}

if (bar = true) {
    Console.WriteLine("This is true");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("This is false");
}
```

Comment: there are some errors in your code... wonder if this would even compile

Comment: Note that comparing a boolean to true in the form `if (somebool == true)` is widely considered as superfluous code. `if(somebool)` is *generally* preferred, and `if(!somebool)` would be the replacement for `== false`.

Comment: Anthony's suggestion also helps avoid one of the errors in the given code (`bar = true` is an assignment, not a comparison...)

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring a new `bar` inside each `if` block, so it's not a valid identifier outside of that scope. You need to declare it outside of your `if` blocks, like this

```
bool bar = false;
if (foo == "True")
{
    bar = true;
}
if (foo == "False")
{
    bar = false;
}

if (bar == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is true");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is false");
}
```

Or for that matter, this would work just as well:

```
bool bar = (foo == "True");

if (bar == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is true");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is false");
}
```

Or even:

```
Console.WriteLine("This is {0}", foo == "True");
```

Comment: Basically the second check is not necessary. It will be false anyway

Comment: @treze Yes, I was trying to modify the original code as little as possible in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to parse:

```
string foo = Console.ReadLine();
bool bar;
if (!bool.TryParse(foo, out bar))
    // inform the user, maybe have them try again

Console.WriteLine("This is {0}", bar);
```

Comment: +1 For that matter, eliminate the final `if` block entirely and just call: `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is {0}", bar));` :)

Comment: Even better: `Console.WriteLine("This is {0}", bar);`. If you're doing more with the boolean, an `if/else` block may be entirely appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You're messing up the scope of your variables.

`bar` only exists within the scope of your `if` statement.

Declare it outside the first `if` statement.

Also, this is not a comparison: `if (bar = true)`

This is: `if (bar == true)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating bar inside 2 different if statements. Their scope is limited to those ifs. When execution leaves the ifs, neither bar is visible (hence why they don't conflict with each other). Try something more like this:

```
bool bar = false;
if (foo == "True")
{
    bar = true;
}
if (foo == "False")
{
    bar = false;
}

if (bar == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is true");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is false");
}
```

Or for all around better code:

```
bool bar = foo == "True";
Console.WriteLine("This is " + bar);
```

Comment: This won't compile since `bar` is not definitely assigned before you read it. You should initialise it to false in the declaration.

Comment: Wasn't thinking about that. My mind was too fogged over with how horrible all the original code is.

Answer (score 0):

`bar` variable should be declared out of scope of `if`/`else` statement

```
bool bar;
if (foo == "True")
{
    bar = true;
}
else
{
    bar = false;
}
```

p.s. you can also use `bool.Parse` method for assign bool value.

Answer (score 0):

Declare bar outside the scope of those ifs. When the block in which they are declared closes they are forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, you define `bar` inside each `if`-block. It is not visible outside the respective `if`-blocks. They are said to have a local **[scope](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx)**.

Second, you musst use `bar == true` instead of `bar = true`. `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the equality operator.

The following will work:

```
string foo = Console.ReadLine();
bool bar;

if (foo == "True")
    bar = true;

if (foo == "False")
    bar = false;

if (bar == true)
    Console.WriteLine("This is true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("This is false");
```

Answer (score 0):

Bar is a local variable in your code. You need to take it out the if statement block